# PHP Syntax error even when other servers do not report errors

Tags: php, syntax

I am a PHP developer and I wouldn't have posted this question here if only this error shows up on ALL machines I tested it with.

I currently get this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in api.php on line 51
```

I have here the exact copy of `api.php` and I tell you that I can't see any error in the code

http://pastebin.com/3xe1qnyR

In fact, the same code runs in my local development machine (PHP 5.3) but it still fails on the production machine (PHP 5.2.17)

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: Not an answer, but a conceptual mistake is using a development machine  and a production machine with different versions of PHP, especially major releases.

Comment: yeah, I was lazy to check the specifications of the development machine since this was a small job. But I will keep that in mind! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using anonymous function at line 51, which is only supported by php 5.3+, the exact reason why it works on your dev machine with php5.3 and not on ze production with 5.2

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: yeah, i just figured that out few minutes ago. I thought the error was on `array_walk`, turns out it's on the `function` keyword! thanks. Will accept in 10mins (SO time restrictions)